# Get Laravel Router output sent

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm working in an API and sometimes it brokes and send some data that's not a valid JSON.

I want to check if the return value of each request is a valid JSON.

How can I **listen to each request output**?

Maybe on `Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router` or on `Laravel\Lumen\Application`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register a Middleware that runs after the request has been sent to the server, right?

For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AfterMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        // Perform validation action on $response? 

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mozammil said, just need a Middleware to do it. Follow how it sens at final.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Mockery\Exception;

class AfterMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        /** @var Response $response */
        $response = $next($request);

        // Response content are a JSON?
        if (!$this->isJson($response->content())){
            // Not a JSON!!
            // Log everywhere
        }

        return $response;
    }

    private function isJson($string) {
        json_decode($string);
        return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
    }
}
```

I'm using **Lumen**, then I added it to `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'afterMiddleware' => App\Http\Middleware\AfterMiddleware::class
]);
```

And finally added middleware to my `api` routes:

```
$router->group([
    'middleware' => 'afterMiddleware',
    'prefix' => 'api'
], function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
        return response(["success"=>true]);
    });

    $router->get('/bug/', function () use ($router) {
        return "I'm not a JSON and it will catch on AfterMiddleware handle";
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice. If you are using PHP 7.3+, there's also a better way for [Error Handling in JSON](https://laravel-news.com/php-7-3-json-error-handling).